# notation question — {(x, 13) | - 6 ≤ x ≤ 9} sets? inequality? domain?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

My daughter was asked if the following represents a function.

```
{(x, 13) | - 6 ≤ x ≤ 9}
```

and I haven't a clue. How does one read this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the set definition of "function"?

Comment: A "function" $f: Domain\to Codomain$ is a set, $f = \{(\alpha,\beta)|\alpha \in Domain; \beta \in Codomain\}$ were for each $x\in Domain$ there is exactly *one* term $(x, \beta)\in f$ where the first term is $x$.  .... So if $Domain = [-6,9]$ is the set of orders pairs $(x,13)$ where $x \in Domain$ satisfy the definition?

Comment: Suppose we wrote this as $f(x) = 13;  x\in [-6,9]$.  Is that a function? Is "$f(x)=13; x\in [-6,9]$" the same thing as $\{(x,13)|-6\le x \le 9\}$?  In which context are they the same, in which are they different.

Comment: @fleablood got it. Thank you.